# Debug start path with Netbeans 7.3.1. (Maven -> Java Application)

Tags: debugging, maven, netbeans, config

I have a question about how to configure Netbeans 7.3.1 to be able to debug my Maven - Java Application? So I can use my breakpoints..

This is my setup:

- Netbeans 7.3.1
- Maven 3.0.5
- A Java Application (JDK 7) with Maven

In my POM file I'm using those maven-plugins:

- maven-compiler-plugin (2.3.2)
- maven-jar-plugin (2.4)
- maven-dependency-plugin (2.7)

---> When I build my project, a .jar file + my dependency files will be exported to my outpuDirectory specified in my configuration of the maven-jar-plugin & maven-dependency-plugin. (This path is just somewhere else on my computer instead of in the default Target folder)

```
<configuration>
    <outputDirectory>C:\Some local path..</outputDirectory>
    ...
</configuration>
```

How can I config in Netbeans that I could debug my project from this outputDirectory?
I'm new in remote debugging so please be specific in your answers.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Open your maven project in NB. Right click on the project node and choose "debug".